# Vuex-persistedstate does not work after refreshing a page

Tags: vue.js

I am making a spa app with laravel and vue, and I would like to keep my login information in vuex's state after refreshing a page.

I typed

```sh
sudo npm install vuex-persistedstate
```

and installed  Vuex-persistedstate and set the plugins as below.

```js
import Vue from 'vue' import Vuex from 'vuex'

import auth from './auth'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth,
        plugins: [createPersistedState()],
    }
})

export default store
```

I expected my data to be kept after refreshing a page but it was not.

I checked what is going on, and it seems the plugin object was empty.

it seems that I cannot import the plugins for some reason, but I do not know why.
Could someone help me, please?

my module file

```js
const state = {
    user: null,
    salonId: null
}

const getters = {
    check: state => !! state.user,
    checkSalonId: state => {return state.salonId},
}

const mutations = {
    setUser (state, user) {
        state.user = user
    },
    setSalonId (state, salonId) {
        state.salonId = salonId
    }
}

const actions = {
    async currentUser (context) {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/user')
        const user = response.data || null
        context.commit('setUser', user)
    },
    async logout (context) {
        context.commit('setUser', null)
        context.commit('setSalonId', null)
    },
    async currentSalon (context, salonId) {
        context.commit('setSalonId', salonId)
    }
}

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state,
    getters,
    mutations,
    actions,
}
```

Comment: This is what I mean. You're questioning, but not take care the answers.

Comment: Oh sorry I just did not notice your answer. I was not notified for some reason. I always reply to answers. 
Thanks for your answer. I was wondering about this forever.

Comment: haha, ok I see it now. Thanks for your attention 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You placed `plugins` in the wrong place. `plugins` should be inline with `modules`, not inside `modules`.

Please take a look at this differences.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth,
        plugins: [createPersistedState()]
    }
})
```

**VS**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to setup an option object with the modules you wanna persist. In this example i'm persisting the user module from my store (haven't include the import code)

```
const persistedStateOptions = {
  paths: [
    'user',
  ]
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user,
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState(persistedStateOptions)]
})
```

Comment: Tried it, but it did not work. it seems the problem is not with the paths..

Answer (score 0):

Look at difference in paths.This worked for me.

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';
    Vue.use(Vuex);

   export default    new Vuex.Store({
   strict:true,
    modules:{
    party,
    contract
   },
   plugins: [createPersistedState(
    {
        paths:['party.selectedParty']
    }
  )],
   });
```

Where party is the module name and  selectedParty is the name of module state.
Now  this plugin only taking care of selectedParty state. 
The vue components that get data via state from DB should be kept out of this plugin.